# Find limiting distribution of $(\bar{X}_n−1)^2$ where $\bar{X}_n$ is the sample mean

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

> Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n,...$ be iid Poisson random variables with parameter $\theta$. We wish to estimate $f(\theta) = (\theta−1)^2$. For all values of $\theta$, find a limiting distribution for $g(X_n) = \left(\bar{X}_n−1\right)^2$ where $\bar{X}_n$ is the sample mean.

I have considered using the MGF approach. I assumed this: The MGF for the sample mean is just the MGF of the sum of Poisson RVs divided by $n.$ However, I was struggling to find the limit of this to form a conclusion.

I have also considered using the CDF approach but am unsure of how to calculate the CDF of $X_n$ in order to substitute the value that I need.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you use central limit theorem?

Comment: The limiting distribution of $(\bar{X}_n-1)^2$ is degenerate.

Comment: @d.k.o. I suspect your comment misses the point. Suppose $X_i,\, i=1,2,3,\ldots$ are i.i.d. with finite variance $\sigma^2$ and expectation $\mu.$ Let $\overline X_n = (X_1+\cdots+X_n)/n.$ Then the limiting distribution of $\overline X_n$ is degenerate in the sense that you seem to intend. But $$ \frac{\overline X_n - \mu}{\sigma/\sqrt n} \to N(0,1) $$ in distribution.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Clearly, for $\theta=1$, $n(\bar{X}_n-1)^2\xrightarrow{d} \chi_1^2$.

Comment: @d.k.o. : So that is probably the kind of answer that is sought here.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to guess what is meant by the limit distribution of a sequence whose limit distribution is actually degenerate. Possibly, it is 
$$
\sqrt{n}\left( \left(\bar{X}_n−1\right)^2 - (\theta-1)^2\right) = \underbrace{\sqrt{n}\left(\bar{X}_n−\theta\right)}_{\xrightarrow{d}\, \mathcal N(0,\theta)}\cdot \underbrace{\left(\bar{X}_n+\theta-2\right)}_{\xrightarrow{p}\,2\theta-2} \xrightarrow{d}\, \mathcal N(0,\theta(2\theta-2)^2)
$$
if $2\theta-2\neq 0$, i.e. $\theta\neq 1$. The last convergence is due to Slutsky's theorem.

If $\theta=1$, then 
$$n\left(\bar{X}_n-1\right)^2\xrightarrow{d}\chi^2_1$$ 
as [d.k.o.](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/140541/d-k-o) stated in the comment.